# Saxon-He 9.8 s9Api Transform function throwing: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Failed to read input file exception

Tags: java, transformation, saxon

I was trying to perform XSLT2.0 transformation using java SaxonHE9-8-0-12J s9api. I could see the html file being created but it is throwing the exception : "net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Failed to read input file".

I would like to return return the final transformed XML as string.

Below is the code i was trying to execute:

```
public String runXSLT(String xsltFile, String strInputXML, boolean cacheEnabled,boolean traceEnabled) throws SaxonApiException, ValidityException, ParsingException {

        Processor proc = new Processor(false);
        XsltCompiler comp = proc.newXsltCompiler();
        XsltExecutable exp = comp.compile(new StreamSource(new File(xsltFile))); //compiled form of stylesheet
        StringReader strRdr = new StringReader(strInputXML);
        StreamSource strSrc = new StreamSource(strRdr);

        DocumentBuilder docBuild = proc.newDocumentBuilder();
        XdmNode source = docBuild.build(strSrc);
        XsltTransformer trans = exp.load();
        trans.setInitialContextNode(source);
        File f = new File("C://Data//transformedXML.html");
        Serializer out = proc.newSerializer();
        out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "html");
        out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");
        out.setOutputFile(f);
        trans.setDestination(out);
        trans.transform();
        return trans.toString();

    }
```

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: First question: on which line is it failing? The stack trace for the exception will tell you. Second question: what is in the string xsltFile? I'm puzzled by the comment "compiled form of stylesheet". Finally, `trans.toString()` makes no sense: the string representation of an XsltTransformer is not going to be of any interest. Please edit the question to address these points.

Comment: Thank you and I'm glad to see the reply straight from you Michael. Your questions helped me to revisit the code and correct the issues. I'm using below code as i need bytearray as response back to my original call.  <code> StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        Serializer out = proc.newSerializer(sw);
        out.setOutputWriter(sw);
        trans.setDestination(out);
        trans.transform();  
  return sw.toString().getBytes(); </code>